# Do "Warning Logs" effect a Application performance in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-warnings

My Unity project have many "Warning Log" in UnityEngine (maybe over a hundreds)
Do this logs effect a decrease performance when play apk at device?

(sorry aboud short english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the warnings occur during the game or only on the first scene or only on compile or are they constant?

You can suppress warnings if you feel they are not going to hamper performance, such as a warning about an upcoming depreciated method etc.

Have a look here; https://www.anton.website/suppressing-warnings-in-unity/

Logging in general can decrease performance, especially if it's running constantly in an Update etc.

Comment: occur only first scene in editor. Is it affect at apk?

Comment: I'd suggest that it isn't going to slow down much but the exact warning is going to be the question here. Unity throws out warnings on startup for all sorts of things, many are innocuous but some may be important.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do.
Unity also logs in builds, since you can inspect the logfile to detect bugs (e.g. after a crash).

You should try to avoid logging unnecessary information by using `UNITY_EDITOR` compiler directive.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
Debug.Log("only appears in unity editor");
#endif
```

Comment: Also note that you can turn off logging in builds by going to `Build settings -> Player Settings -> Other settings` and at the bottom you have a matrix of all log levels and what to output

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for all logs not only warning,
I had a project with terrible framerate in a project before, The fix for that was to remove all the logs,
As I found that unity uses it in build version too, even if release and even if I remove it from playerSettings it will still affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does affect performance. You can choose to enable and disable the logs though without removing them completely. I tend to only use the logs on Editor. You can put something like

```
 #if UNITY_EDITOR
   Debug.Log("sample");
 #endif
```

Or you can add your own scripting define symbol in the Player Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah they do affect it but that isn't only for warning logs. Any logs will affect the performance. You should try to remove any `Debug.Log` commands if they aren't required anymore and fix any warning logs if it is possible.